# Convert rectangular image to square image without trimming

Tags: php, laravel, image-resizing, intervention

First, I apologize for my English .

I have a **vertical** or **horizontal** rectangular image. (As shown) .

I want to become a square. Without cutting. (As shown) .

It is better used Intervention Image Library .

thanks for your help .

[image]

Comment: Already a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

I would say this is non exclusive php question...

1. Check dimensions let `h = height` and `w = weight`.
2. If `h > w` make new pic with square of h place the pic in `(h-w) / 2` top
   position and zero on right.
3. If `w > h` make new pic with square of w place the pic in `(w-h) / 2` right
   position and zero on top.